# is there an API that querys an amazon like site (or amazon) and gets the market price of an item?

Tags: php, api

is there an API that querys an amazon like site (or amazon) and gets the market price of an item?

preferablly in php, but, doesnt have to be.

anyway, thanks

thanks =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this could help you in a great way ::

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/642-PHP-A-PHP-XML-class-to-access-Amazon-API-they-released.html

a PHP class for easy access to Amazon API. :)

EDIT: i havent used it myself, but i assume that it should certainly be having some way to get Prices etc as you require it.

Comment: but the documentation doesnnt say which amazon web service it queries, meaning which i have to sign up for....

Comment: you will first need to register and obtain a valid developer token. You can get your token here at this address: http://www.amazon.com/webservices

Theres a description for the class on that given link, maybe it will help.