# Get Item/Product Price in Amazon using ASIN

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-marketplace

Is there any way on how we can get the price for a specific product (*or item*) in amazon using ASIN and for a specific seller?

I have seen [Amazon Marketplace Web Service (Amazon MWS)](https://developer.amazonservices.com/index.html) but I think it's for sellers who want to develop an application to access *their* product. It doesn't allow me to create an account so I can get `MWS` keys because it asks for `Amazon Seller Account` and to which I don't need a seller's account since I'm only interested for the prices of the product and I'm not a seller.

I have a list of [ASIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Standard_Identification_Number) which I need to get their prices for a specific seller (*specifically from AMAZON only*). I already know how to create AWS keys. What will I do next? I'm looking for a function or method which asks for `ASIN` and returns prices offered by a specific seller.

Here's the articles I read:

- [Amazon Marketplace API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737695/amazon-marketplace-api)
- [amazon product advertising api - item lookup request working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460936/amazon-product-advertising-api-item-lookup-request-working-example)
- [How to get ASIN and price from AMAZON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274798/how-to-get-asin-and-price-from-amazon)
- [Amazon Product Advertising API: Get Product Detail URL from ASIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155439/amazon-product-advertising-api-get-product-detail-url-from-asin)
- [is there an API that querys an amazon like site (or amazon) and gets the market price of an item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378004/is-there-an-api-that-querys-an-amazon-like-site-or-amazon-and-gets-the-market)

I'm very new with this stuff and it's very advance for me. Hope somebody will give me a good guide that will be able to fulfill my needs.

Answer (score 16):

Your view on Amazon MWS is correct: It is an API that lets merchants sell stuff on Amazon, so unless the specific seller you are looking for is in fact your own company, MWS won't be an option.

What you are looking for is now part of the Amazon Product Advertising API (the name may be a bit misleading). This API lets you query for information that is accessible for everyone.

You will need to call [ItemLookup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) with the following parameters:

- ItemId = a single ASIN
- MerchantID = the seller ID of the specific seller you're looking for (if you omit this parameter, you'll get data for all sellers, or just the "buybox/best price" seller, depending on the ResponseGroup you chose)
- ResponseGroup = "Offers", "OfferListing" or "OfferFull" (play with all three to pick the one that most closely matches what you're looking for)

You will have to do this for one ASIN at a time (technically, you could do up to 10 at a time, but results may not be what you'd expect)

Comment: can you clarify (technically, you could do up to 10 at a time, but results may not be what you'd expect) I am using MWS and requesting 10 at a time and I think results are not always correct,

Comment: @Ratna : if you specify more than one ASIN, you will get mixed results depending on the `ResponseGroup`. I haven't tried them all, but if I recall correctly, some ResponseGroups behave as expected and return data for all specified ASINs while others end up only return data for one ASIN.